# Does Remove["Global`*"] on one kernel clear definitions and functions on another kernel?

Tags: kernel

While I was running a quite long evaluation on one kernel(kernel 1), I executed Remove["Global`*"]; on the other kernel(kernel 2).

How will this affect my current evaluation on kernel 1? Will it remove the evaluations done before I run Remove?

Comment: It shouldn't. But, to convince yourself of this, try it yourself: open two kernels, run a long-ish computation in one, and try clearing/removing in the other, and check again.

Comment: Thanks @J.M.. That's a relief. I'll try to check it what you suggested after my current computation is done.